# How to use Hibernate JPA 2 Metamodel Generator?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa-2.0

When I learned Hibernate JPA 2 Metamodel Generator according to http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/jpamodelgen/reference/en-US/html_single/, it is working all right.
    But when I tried to generate these metamodel by run `mvn compile`, it only generated corresponding classes and a strange folder 'generated-sources' in target folder as below and does not generated corresponding java files in source folder. 
[image]

Below is my related configuration in pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
                <id>process</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <processors>
                    <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                </processors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

So, **my question is**: is this expected behavior? If yes, does it mean that I need to compile code before I use metamodel each time?. If no, how can I generate java files in source code folder?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But when I tried to generate these metamodel by run mvn compile, it only generated corresponding classes and a strange folder 'generated-sources' in target folder as below and does not generated corresponding java files in source folder.

The default folder for the generated meta classes is `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/apt` where `${project.build.directory}` is `target` by default. So the generated meta classes should be under `target/generated-sources/apt` directory (as I can guess from your screenshot the meta classes are generated).

If you want to change this behavior you can configure the plugin to generate the meta classes to another folder by using the `outputDirectory` element as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>process</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
            <processors>
                <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
            </processors>
             <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/generated</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

And don't forget to add the new folder into your class path otherwise your project might not build.

> is this expected behavior?

yes

> If yes, does it mean that I need to compile code before I use metamodel each time?

yes, but if you don't change or add new entities you can use the generaed classes provided you run `mvn compile` at least once.

> If no, how can I generate java files in source code folder?

I don't recommend to do it :-) I mean mixing the generated classes with the source code is not a good idea. If you don't like the `target` folder use any other folder as described above.

Comment: The meta classes are indeed generated in target/generated-sources/apt. But they are also generated in target/classes folder. It means same meta classes are generated in two folders. Is it expected behavior?

Comment: Unless you have something that you haven't posted it should not be possible according to the configuration you posted. But the compiled classses should be under `target/classes`; the source code should not be there, i.e. the source classes, for example, like *MyEntity_.java* go to the `generated-sources` folder whereas the compiled classes like *MyEntity_.class* will be under `target/classes` folder.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is really helpful.

Comment: @Xiaoyuan , did you solve the problem? Is this answer acceptable?

Comment: @ДмитрийКулешов, yes, have you got a problem? In fact, I haven't encountered any problem. As I raised above, I just confuse its behavior.

Comment: @Xiaoyuan, I just propose to you to accept the answer